# Why css max-width are set, but div still expanded?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I have a problem with navigation .nav .dropdown-menu and .text-truncate on mobile view when content text length is too long, it can't be ellipsis.

I have try set max-width 100% to .dropdown-menu so children element only expand maximum to parent width.

[screenshot actualy happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTqKr.jpg)

here the code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark shadow fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-husr-navbar" aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="collapse-husr-navbar" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbar-husr-right">
        <div class="d-block d-sm-flex">
          <div class="p-2 text-truncate">
            <span class="d-inline">
              <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
              <small><span id="husr-branch-name">DUMMY BRANCH A</span></small>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="d-inline d-sm-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline">Menu</span>
          </a>
<!-- here the first I try to put max-width:100%; so children element can't push parent to expand, but not work. :( -->
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show" style="max-width:100%">
            <span class="dropdown-item-text text-nowrap" style="
">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <span id="husr-user-name">Staff User</span>
              (<em><span id="husr-user-type">STAFF</span></em>)
            </span>

<!-- here the second I try to put max-width:100%; so children element can't push parent to expand, but also not work. :( -->
            <span class="dropdown-item-text head-email"  style="max-width:100%">
<!-- here the third time put max-width:100%; so children element can't push parent to expand, butthis also not work. :( -->
              <div class="text-truncate" style="max-width:100%">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                <span id="husr-user-username">i_mean_it_to_be_ellipsis_text_truncated_but_container_div_still_expanded</span>
<!-- yeah the text has no space because it contain an email that should be nospace -->
              </div>
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[screenshot expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX66F.jpg)

Comment: Please try to include everything necessary to be able to reproduce the issue (in this case your CSS).

Comment: We would need to see your CSS. You can look at the [`text-overflow` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) and see if that works.

Comment: @BaliBalo as I mention I use bootstrap 4 and no other css that necessary to this case.

Comment: @Leo the ellipsis works for me with your code as you provided it, when only using the bootstrap CSS from their CDN: https://jsfiddle.net/1myp4zu2/ - there is probably something else interfering with it

Comment: @khan other css is unnecessary (I mean I do not overide any of them) I do understand how to use text-overflow and it already handled by bootstrap on class .text-truncate 
the problem should be whay my container keep expand as text expand?

Comment: @BaliBalo hmm... that weird I still saw it overflowed and not ellipsis... https://imgur.com/a/sHbzQnR

Comment: @Leo Indeed, this is only an issue on smaller viewport sizes (under 576px). Edited my answer.

Comment: @BaliBalo yes thats what I ask. I don't what cause this happen when I change to position: absolute; left:0; right:0; it works but display are out from .navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `text-overflow` to work, you need a max-width but also `overflow: hidden`. You should be able to remove the `text-truncate` div and use this CSS:

```
.head-email {
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

From the [MDN documentation for text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow):

> The `text-overflow` property doesn't force an overflow to occur. To make text overflow its container you have to set other CSS properties: `overflow` and `white-space`.

**EDIT:**
In your case bootstrap under 576px doesn't limit the size of the navbar itself. Adding a `max-width: 100%;` on your div with class `navbar-collapse` fixes smaller viewport sizes.

Comment: thank you. yeah the problem is on .navbar-collapse thank you... I gonna override those on smaller view port... thank you...